# admin tool to see tags assigned to at least one question but fewer than X questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

The interface should be similar to the new tags interface.  This would help 10k users find things that have been assigned to misspelt, but not new, tags.

Comment: misplet       ?

Comment: oh, mispelt. heh.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tags and then work your way back from the last page...

Comment: That doesn't give you recently used tags, using the new tags method I was able to find where someone had tagged his or her post as pthon, but the next time someone makes the same error I won't be able to find it because it isn't a new tag.

Answer (score 0):

The 10k rep user tools has this information in two places, both on the "dashboard" and in a seperate report page.